# vb.net why i can't use MimeType on second project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

before this i can use MimeType on firstproject, everything is fine..

[image]

but now.. when i created another project (second project)
i can't use MimeType anymore... why?

[image]

Comment: Can you give a bit more information. From what namespace is the File object? Because System.IO.File is a static class that cannot be instantiated. So... also on that note, are the usings in both projects the same?

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg it's google drive api sir,  set `Public file as File` then follow my code in image above

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg problem solved! i change form name to other name, before this i named form "File" lmao..... i just change it to "file_upload" and it's working fine sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved!
just change form name to other name
in this case i change it to "file_upload" and it's working fine!